# Set form value without user input

Tags: python, django

Initially I was populating my form with an initial value and disabling the field to let the user know that the option that has been randomly selected for this form.  But I've run into a few issues and it just seems better to not even show this in my form to the user but notify them later with [messages](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/messages/#displaying-messages).  Though I'm not quite sure how to do this.  I need to assign a color to my job model on form submission for the job.  I have:

This is what I use to pick what color to assign to each new job.

```
  cur_jobs = Job.objects.filter(enddate__gte=(datetime.date.today()-timedelta(days=7)))
  all_colors = Color.objects.all()
  cur_colors = []
  for i in cur_jobs:
    cur_colors.append(i.color)
  aval_colors = [x for x in all_colors if x not in cur_colors]
  choice = random.choice(aval_colors)
```

These are my models:

```
class Job(models.Model):
    ---other stuff---
    jobnum = models.CharField("Job Number",max_length=6, blank=False,unique=True,error_messages={'unique':'This Job Number is already taken! =)'})
    color = models.ForeignKey('Color')

class Color(models.Model):
    color = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False)

    def natural_key(self):
        return (self.color)

    def __str__(self): #python 3.3. is __str__
        return self.color
```

How can I take `choice` and submit it as a `color` with the `jobform` instance?

Job form:

```
class LimitedJobForm(forms.ModelForm):
jobnum = forms.CharField(label='Job Number')
class Meta:
    model = Job
    fields = ['jobnum','color','client','status']
```

Comment: Where is the `jobform` instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want `color` to be automatically set, and if you don't even want it to be displayed to the user, do not put it in your form:

```
class LimitedJobForm(forms.ModelForm):

    jobnum = forms.CharField(label='Job Number')

    class Meta:
        model = Job
        fields = ['jobnum', 'client', 'status']  # no 'color' field
```

Instead, set the color directly on the model instance in your view, after validating the form and before saving it:

```
form = LimitedJobForm(request.POST)

if form.is_valid():
    form.instance.color = pick_random_color()
    form.save()
```

Comment: Thank you, I figured it was something simple like this.